# Problem With Custom Unity-Greeter background

Tags: unity, lightdm, desktop-background, unity-greeter

So I have this cool background I like. I set it as my background, but in Unity-Greeter, (Not the lock screen) I just see the default "bruised" wallpaper for 14.04. Ick. Does anyone know how to make my custom wallpaper show on the login screen? I know new wallpapers can be added to the default wallpaper set. (I think when you use xfce4, the default Debian background and the Debian Inksplat background appear alongside the other available wallpapers. Also,after using xfce4, the default xfce background becomes your unity-greeter wallpaper, but when you login to Unity, your previously selected desktop background still appears. If you change the wallpaper and back, the xfce greeter background dissapears.) How can I make unity-greeter diaplay my custom wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).  Just click Tweaks, Login Settings, and then "click the button to change the login screen background".  If you want your session wallpaper to be used, there's a one click button for that, "set the same background as the current desktop background"

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. When I change it, and log out, i just see a dark purple background. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with the Numix-Circle and Numix-Dark GTK theme installed.

Comment: Sorry! It works for me. In fact I tried it before answering. I set it to the Sea Fury picture that was included in /usr/share/backgrounds. Maybe see if that one works for you? If so maybe it is something to do with your specific image.

Comment: See edited answer above.

Comment: I'm not using an image from /usr/share/backgrounds. It's in my pictures folder and I downloaded it from the internet, so it still isn't working. I've also tried ten different images-theres obviously nothing wrong with the one I used originally because they all give me a dark purple login screen.

Comment: I tried a background image of my own and I got the purple screen.  I don't know what is special about the Sea Fury picture.  If you figure it out, please come back and post an answer.

Comment: Maybe the picture has to be from /usr/share/backgrounds.

Comment: This was still bugging me.  I resized my background image to 2560 x 1600 px (same as the Sea Fury) and then it worked.  Based on my extensive testing (not) it looks like the login image must be a jpeg image sized exactly at 2560 x 1600.